# What happened to spinning wheels which were burned?

Tags: plot-explanation, maleficent

The main plot of the movie is the curse which *Maleficent* cast on the princess: She would prick her thumb on a spinning wheel and fall asleep, so people burned all the spinning wheels in the country. But what happened to spinning wheels which were burned?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, both grammatically and due to the fact there are no fairgrounds in the movie: there is obviously translation problem here... could you provide a better translation, or perhaps ask the question in your native language (Czech, is it?), so someone else with better translation abilities can quickly translate it back into English?

Comment: I've clarified the bits I understood, but I'm not certain enough to add the actual question into the body, is it what happened to the remains of the burned spinning wheels, or how they were burned or something?

Comment: Don't understand what's  your argument here. It's best to please edit your question and clarify everything.

Answer (score 4):

If you watch the movie, after the wheels are burned they are stored in a deep dungeon room in the castle. This is where the princess finds them and ultimately pricks her finger on the needle of one of them.

(We can leave aside the startling number of mostly intact wooden wheels after they've been through fire as more movie magic.)